# Csv to Json :- Using csv.extend function but getting extra line character while concatenating [

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have one csv file with below content

```
signOffDate,fundEntityType,fundId,benchmarkIds,source,returnType
30-Sep-17,ENTITY_ID,44182,MAN,IP,TR    
30-Nov-17,ENTITY_ID,44182,VAN,IP,TR
```

I want to convert in into json file having content using python

```
 {
    "fundId": [ "44182"],
    "signOffDate": "30-Sep-17",
    "fundEntityType": "ENTITY_ID",
    "source": "IP",
    "returnType": "TR",
    "benchmarkIds": [ "MAN"]
},
{
    "fundId": ["44182"],
    "signOffDate": "30-Nov-17",
    "fundEntityType": "ENTITY_ID",
    "source": "IP",
    "returnType": "TR",
    "benchmarkIds": [ "VAN"]
}
```

The python code I have tried so far is below. It has some issues. I am stuck at it.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile ='sample.csv'
jsonfile ='sample.json'


def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
                   csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:[row[field[i]]] if field[i]=='benchmarkIds' or  field[i]=='fundId' else row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}]);
    convert_write_json(csv_rows, json_file)

#Convert csv data into json
def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
        #f.write(json.dumps(data))


read_CSV(csvfile,jsonfile)
```

Comment: You seem to indicate you have a problem with your code, but I don't see code anywhere...

Comment: What's your question exactly ? And where's your code ?

Comment: It got submitted before I could add. Please running my code. You will see the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `append` instead of `extend`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
import json
import pprint

with open("file", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    field = reader.fieldnames
    csv_rows = []
    for row in reader:
        csv_rows.append({field[i]:[row[field[i]]] if field[i]=='benchmarkIds' or  field[i]=='fundId' else row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))})

for i in csv_rows:
    pprint.pprint(i)

print(json.dumps(csv_rows))
```

**Output:**

```
{'benchmarkIds': ['MAN'],
 'fundEntityType': 'ENTITY_ID',
 'fundId': ['44182'],
 'returnType': 'TR    ',
 'signOffDate': '30-Sep-17',
 'source': 'IP'}
{'benchmarkIds': ['VAN'],
 'fundEntityType': 'ENTITY_ID',
 'fundId': ['44182'],
 'returnType': 'TR',
 'signOffDate': '30-Nov-17',
 'source': 'IP'}

[{"fundId": ["44182"], "signOffDate": "30-Sep-17", "fundEntityType": "ENTITY_ID", "source": "IP", "returnType": "TR    ", "benchmarkIds": ["MAN"]}, {"fundId": ["44182"], "signOffDate": "30-Nov-17", "fundEntityType": "ENTITY_ID", "source": "IP", "returnType": "TR", "benchmarkIds": ["VAN"]}]
```

Comment: in this file=sample.csv??

Comment: Yes. It is your source cvs file

Comment: found one bug in  your code. I want the output in json file in which we have double quotes for properties and values. And your o/p has single quotes.

Comment: That is because i have not converted it to JSON because already know how to do that and i used pprint to display the output. Anyway i have updated the snippet.

Comment: print json.dumps(csv_rows)  it is giving invalid syntax. (highlighting json) Using python 3.6 and imported the json in beginning also.

Comment: in python 3 use print(json.dumps(csv_rows))

Comment: please edit same in above answer so that I can accept it.